# Panic: runtime error: index out of range

Tags: go

Sorry if this seems pretty basic but why am I getting this error? I dont see any slices/arrays out of range.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    s:= [...]int{1,2,3}
    rev(s[:])
    fmt.Println(s)
}

func rev(input []int) []int {
    var j int
    l:=len(input)-1
    for i:=0; i<l;i++ {
        j= input[len(input)-i]
        input=append(input, j)
        i++
    }
    return input[:l]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[...]int{1,2,3}` is not a slice. It is an array of capacity 3.
See "[golang-101-hacks: Array](https://nanxiao.gitbooks.io/golang-101-hacks/content/posts/array.html)"

If you try to append a fourth element... that will be out of range.

But here `s[:]` [transforms it into a slice](https://blog.golang.org/slices).

The actual '`index out of range`' comes from `input[len(input)-i]` which, with `i=0`, means `input[len(input)]`: out of range.

This would work better ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OXSZ3Z42oG)) (no out of range)

The final `fmt.Println(s)` was still print the original array, not the return of `rev()` (which is ignored).
This prints the "expected" result (using append, so mutating and adding to the slice):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := [...]int{1, 2, 3}
    t := rev(s[:])
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(t)
}

func rev(input []int) []int {
    var j int
    l := len(input) - 1
    for i := 0; i <= l; i++ {
        j = input[l-i]
        input = append(input, j)
    }
    return input
}
```

Result:

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3 3 2 1]
```

This ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Mw5QtCy2QO)) would actually reverse the slice:

```
var j int
var res []int
l := len(input) - 1
for i := 0; i <= l; i++ {
    j = input[l-i]
    res = append(res, j)
}
return res
```

Result:

```
[1 2 3]
[3 2 1]
```

Comment: @LukeMann Not sure though, this was an out of range on a slice: I have edited the answer.